# STM32 HAL Library simple C coding error

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I am using the STM32 HAL Library for a micro controller project. In the ADC section I found the following code:

```
uint32_t WaitLoopIndex = 0;                                                                           
/...    
.../                                                                      
/* Delay for ADC stabilization time.                                      */                        
/* Delay fixed to worst case: maximum CPU frequency                       */                        
while(WaitLoopIndex < ADC_STAB_DELAY_CPU_CYCLES)                                                    
{                                                                                                   
  WaitLoopIndex++;                                                                                  
}
```

It is my understanding that this code will most likely get optimized away since `WaitLoopIndex` isn't used anywhere else in the function and is not declared volatile, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically yes, though from my experiences with compilers for embedded targets, that loop will not get optimised out. If you think about it, having a pointless loop is not really a construct you are going to see in a program unless the programmer does it on purpose, so I doubt many compilers bothers to optimise for it.

The fact that you have to make assumptions about how it might be optimised though means it most certainly is a bug, and one of the worst types at that. More than likely ST wanted to only use C in their library, so did this instead of the inline assembler delay that they should have used. But since the problem they are trying to solve is heavily platform dependent, an annoying platform/compiler dependent solution is unavoidable, and all they have done here is try to hide that dependency.

Declaring the variable volatile will help, but you still really have no idea how long that loop is taking to execute without making assumptions about how the compiler is building it. This is still very bad practice, though if they added an assert reminding you to check the delay manually that might be passable.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the compiler and the optimization level. To confirm the result, just enter debug mode and check the disassembly code of the piece of code.

Comment: I just feel that relying on disassembly is not going to be very maintainable in the long run. What if optimization levels need to be changed later on?